# What is the reason for the npm installation error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tusha\package.json'?

Tags: npm, cmd

I try to install libraries with *npm* on Windows to work with JavaScript, but it shows this error output in Windows command prompt window:

```
C:\Users\tusha>npm install
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\tusha/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\tusha\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tusha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-24T10_37_38_185Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\tusha>
```

Here is also a photo:

[Screen shot of command prompt window with the error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JspDz.png)

The log of the failed installation process:

[The complete log file on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VCsmdvamJERAQwuprbtF5wEgsAjNruU8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Looks like the error is telling you what's wrong, is there a package.json file in the directory where you're running the 'npm install' ? If not, then navigate to the directory that contains the package.json and run the command from there. Basically npm can't install dependencies without knowing what they are.

Answer (score 1):

ERR telling that in your folder directory you are installing some packages through npm. Look like package.json not found in located directory

Before run `npm install` to empty folder you have to initialize the `npm init` to create package.json file. and start installing packages.

Answer (score -1):

`npm install` reads the file *package.json* from the current directory and installs all the packages it depends on. The error message says that there is no such file.

You need to `cd` to the directory the Node.js project (e.g. something you might have checked out from a Git repository) and run `npm install` *there*.

---

Alternatively, if you are trying to install a specific package from the npm repository then you need to:

- `cd` to the directory containing the package you want to add it as a dependency of
- run `npm install name-of-package`

If you don't have a project yet, and want to create one, then:

- `cd` to the directory you want to create your package inside
- `npm init` and follow the prompts

---

Alternatively, if you are trying to install a program from npm globally then **reconsider** as current best practice is to run program with `npx` and not install them as globals. Use the name of the package you want to run as an argument.

```
npx create-react-app
```

If you *really* want to install globally, then use the `-g` switch and the name of the package.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```